# gcc and clang throw "no matching function call" but msvc (cl) compiles and works as expected

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++17, cl

I have written a small function template that joins different containers in a new container:

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

namespace impl
{
    template <typename OutIterator, typename Container, typename ...Containers>
    void join(OutIterator iterator, const Container& container, const Containers& ...containers)
    {        
        for (const auto& item : container)
            *iterator++ = item;

        join(iterator, containers...);  // gcc and clang cannot resolve this call
    }

    template <typename OutIterator, typename Container>
    void join(OutIterator iterator, const Container& container)
    {        
        for (const auto& item : container)
            *iterator++ = item;
    }
}

template <typename OutContainer, typename ...Containers>
OutContainer join(const Containers& ...containers)
{
    OutContainer container;
    auto it = std::inserter(container, container.end());
    impl::join(it, containers...);
    return container;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    vector<string> a = {"one"s, "two"s, "three"s};
    unordered_set<string> b = {"four"s, "five"s };
    auto res = join<unordered_set<string>>(a, b);

    for (auto& i : res)
        cout << i << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Using MSVC (cl.exe) with /std:c++17 the code compiles and works just fine. But when compiling with clang-6.0 or gcc-7.3, a compiler error is thrown. I.e. gcc says

```
no matching function for call to 'join(std::insert_iterator<std::unordered_set<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >&)'
```

So obviously a function with this signature is not defined. But I don't get why it tries to call such a function. Shouldn't it be resolved like this

```
// in main()
join<unordered_set<string>>(a, b);

unordered_set<string> join(const vector<string>& a, const unordered_set<string>& b);
void impl::join(std::insert_iterator<unordered_set<string>> iterator, const vector<string>& a, const unordered_set<string>& b);
void impl::join(std::insert_iterator<unordered_set<string>> iterator, const unordered_set<string>& b);
```

Why does gcc try to instantiate `join(std::insert_iterator<std::unordered_set<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>>>&)` ?

[Here](https://godbolt.org/g/FbSyvK) is an example using the compiler explorer.

Comment: Another nice thing about re-ordering them, is that you can avoid duplicating logic (that for loop).

Comment: This is a very dangerous implementation, same problems as the good old C functions like strcat have! What, if the output iterator reaches the end iterator of the target container???

Comment: @Aconcagua - The output iterator is an inserter. I imagine these two functions being in an `impl` namespace is why they are dangerous "in general".

Comment: @Aconcagua well, the functions in the `impl` namespace are intended to be used from the global scope function `join` only, which uses a insert_iterator, which means it inserts into the container every assignment.

Comment: OK... I personally still would reflect this in the template parameters. Maybe I am a little safety-fanatic? Side note: A little shorter: `auto it = std::back_inserter(container);`...

Comment: @Aconcagua how would you reflect this in the template parameters? I cannot use `back_inserter` because the container can be (like shown in my example) something else than a vector (like a set), which does not have a `push_back` function. `back_inserter_iterator` and `insert_iterator` use different mechanics.

Comment: @Timo `template <typename OutContainer, typename Container>
void join(std::insert_iterator<OutContainer> i, Container const& c);`; `back_inserter`: sorry, oversaw necessity for more flexibility... Could have been nice in other situations, though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

gcc and clang are correct. MSVC still has issues with proper template name lookup (i.e. "two-phase lookup").

`join`, in `join(iterator, containers...)`, is a dependent name. The candidates for finding that name are:

- All names at the point of the template definition. This lookup just finds itself (the variadic overload), not the other overload (the 2-arg one), because it hasn't been declared yet.
- All names that can be found by ADL on its arguments. None of those arguments have `impl` as an associated namespace, so that wouldn't find the other overload either.

In this situation, the fix is trivial: just reorder the two `join()` overloads. This ensures that the 2-arg `join()` will be found by that first bullet point.

---

Note that in C++17, you don't even need two overloads. Just one is fine:

```
template <typename OutIterator, typename Container, typename... Containers>
void join(OutIterator iterator, Container const& container, Container const&... containers) {
    for (auto const& item : container) {
        *iterator++ = item;
    }

    if constexpr(sizeof...(Containers) > 0) {
        join(iterator, containers...);
    }
}
```

---

Also consider using `std::copy()` instead of the loop. Which would actually allow:

```
template <typename OutIterator, typename... Containers>
void join(OutIterator iterator, Container const&... containers) {
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    (iterator = std::copy(begin(containers), end(containers), iterator), ...);
}
```

Comment: MSVC exhibits the correct behavior if you use the /permissive- flag (found on the c/c++->language node of project settings, labelled as "Conformance mode")